# Como retornar valores de duas tabelas distintas php

Tags: php, javascript, json

Sou iniciante e queria criar uma função que me retornasse a partir do nome o cpf, usuario e senha da pessoa no sistema. Onde os campos nome e cpf pertencem a tabela usuarios e os campos usuario e senha pertencem a users.

Forma que tentei e não obtive sucesso

```
          <script type='text/javascript'>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("input[name='nome']").blur(function(){
                                var $cpf = $("input[name='cpf']");
                                var $usuario = $("input[name='usuario']");
                                var $senha = $("input[name='senha']");

                                $.getJSON('function.php',{ 
                                        nome: $( this ).val() 
                                },function( json ){
                                        $cpf.val( json.cpf );
                                        $usuario.val( json.usuario );
                                        $senha.val( json.senha );

                                });
                        });
                });
        </script>
```

Minha function.php

```
     function retorna($nome, $conn){
            $result = "SELECT CPF, USUARIO, SENHA FROM USUARIOS A INNER JOIN USUAR B ON B.NOME = A.NOME WHERE nome = '$nome' LIMIT 1";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
            if($resultado->num_rows){
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
                    $valores['cpf'] = $row['cpf'];
                    $valores['usuario'] = $row['usuario'];
                    $valores['senha'] = $row['senha'];

            }else{
                    $valores['cpf'] = '';
                    $valores['usuario'] = '';
                    $valores['senha'] = '';

            }

            return json_encode($valores);

    }

    if(isset($_GET['nome'])){
            echo retorna($_GET['nome'], $conn);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As duas tabelas são relacionadas? Se sim tenta fazer essa busca por número, como `cod_usuario`. 
Creio eu que não é possível fazer um `select` com `inner` setando 2 tipos diferentes de valores para um mesmo campo.
Nesse caso eu recomendaria que criasse uma view no banco e desse um select por ela. Exemplo :

```
create view vw_user as
  select a.cpf, b.usuario, b.senha  
  from usuario a, user b 
  where a.cod_usuario = b.cod_usuario
;
```

Onde dentro do código em php você coloca a consulta

```
select * from vw_user where nome = $nome
```

Claro, alegando que **o nome do usuario da tabela pessoa é o mesmo que o nome da tabela users**. Caso contrario, sugiro que esse login seja feito pelo numero do cpf, ou que ele utilize outra chave para encontrar o usuário.

EDIT 1: criei um banco fictício para ilustrar o meu pensamento (sem a adição da view, para ficar mais simples)

```
create database logincliente;
use logincliente;

create table pessoa(
cod_pessoa int not null auto_increment primary key,
nome_pessoa varchar(50)
);

create table login(
cod_login int not null auto_increment primary key,
cod_pessoa int not null,
login varchar(50),
senha varchar(50)
);

alter table login add constraint fk_loginPessoa foreign key (cod_pessoa) references pessoa (cod_pessoa);


insert into pessoa(nome_pessoa) values 
('Flávio'),
('Castro'),
('Reginaldo'),
('Péricles');

insert into login (cod_pessoa,login,senha) values 
(1,'flaviko','12345'),
(2,'kastr','stqvb'),
(3,'reginaldo','reginaldo'),
(4,'pokkter','033line');



select p.nome_pessoa, l.login, l.senha from pessoa p, login l where nome_pessoa = 'péricles' and p.cod_pessoa = l.cod_pessoa;
```

Tenta testar esse ultimo select, e veja se é esse o resultado que deseja :)

Comment: Tentei deixar o mesmo script e só alterar meu select depois de criar a view e persiste o erro .

Comment: eu criei um script SQL que ilustrou basicamente o que eu tentei explicar (não usei view, pois não é tão necessário na ocasião)

Comment: seria preciso um javascript como o que eu citei para fazer o preenchimento dos próximos campos

Comment: esse insert que eu fiz você pode adaptar ao seu código

Comment: esse select que eu fiz, é só colocar uma variavel php no meio

Comment: no caso utilizando esse código dentro da minha function.php não dá, acho que preciso buscar um novo script para preencher todos dados a partir de um campo